# ko.computed write function on foreach $data variable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

is it possible use the ko.computed write function on the foreach $data variable like this?

```
<!-- ko foreach: activeAttributes.optionsSplitted -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data">
<!-- /ko -->


vm.activeAttributes.optionsSplitted = ko.computed({
    read: function(){
        return vm.activeAttributes().options().split("-*!*-");      
    },
    write: function(){
        alert("changed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know, you tell us. Did you try that yourself? Did it work as you expected? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I was excepting that when I edit the input text box knockout should call the write function and prompt the alert, but this is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that your computed observable only detects changes on the array, `activeAttributes.optionsSplitted`.  The textboxes are bound to the individual items so since you never actually change the value of `activeAttributes.optionsSplitted`, no alert is made.

If you want to be able to do this, you have a couple of options.

Bind to the `change` event for your inputs so you can do what you want when a value changes in the input.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data, event: { change: $root.changed }">
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/4yKed/))

---

Or, you could map the values to objects that contain observable properties and perform the checks there.  You cannot detect changes on the object itself (any changes will be replacements) so you would have to map the value to an object with the writable-computed property.

```
self.activeAttributes.optionsSplitted = ko.computed(function(){
    var options = self.activeAttributes().options().split("-*!*-");
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(options, function (option) {
        // does not work
        //return ko.computed({
        //    read: function () { return option; },
        //    write: function (value) { alert('changed'); }
        //});
        return {
            value: ko.computed({
                read: function () { return option; },
                write: function (value) { alert('changed'); }
            })
        };
    });
});
```

Then bind to the property.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: value">
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/xp6S7/))

---

These aren't your only options of course, there are probably other things you could do here but these are what come to mind.

Comment: You've given very good solutions. I couldn't think much better.